# How to replace only a string using gettext

Tags: wordpress, gettext

I am using this function to replace Divi with Framework

```
add_filter('gettext', 'translate_text', 10);
add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_text');
function translate_text($translated) {
    $translated = str_ireplace('Divi',  'Framework',  $translated);
      return $translated;
}
```

It works fine as it replaced all instances of Divi with Framework. Now the problem is it also replaces **Divider** to **Frameworkder**

How I can prevent this? I only want Divi to be replaced with my chosen text.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can verify the `length` of translated

Comment: Thanks but how I can achieve this? I have been looking for some resources but still could not find a solution to this. Thanks

Comment: Maybe with an if statement: `if(strlen($translated)==4){ ... }`

Comment: Thanks Fernando, but it does not work. I think there should be a better way to do this

Comment: I think it would be better if you specify what language are you using. PHP?

Comment: Yes Php. I am posting the function in the functions.php file of WordPress and want to replace all instances of Divi with Framework inside my dashboard

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer myself. Just updating this thread in case someone else needs this. It's damn simple by the way. I used `preg_replace`

```
add_filter('gettext', 'translate_text', 10);
add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_text');
function translate_text($translated) {
    $translated = preg_replace('/(Divi\b)/', 'Framework', $translated);
      return $translated;
}
```